# Class not found by FindClass

Tags: java-native-interface

I have some troubles with a non-working call to `FindClass` in my application. I've looked up many questions on this subject but none of these solved my problem...

The JVM creation code:

```cpp
JavaVM *test_jvm;
JNIEnv *test_jenv;

JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK 1.1 VM initialization arguments */
JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
JavaVMOption options[1];
options[0].optionString = classpath;
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4; /* New in 1.1.2: VM version */
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
jint ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&test_jvm, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&test_jenv), &vm_args);
assert(ret == JNI_OK);

assert(test_jenv->FindClass("my/package/MyClass") != 0);
```

The definition of `classpath`:

```cpp
char classpath[] = "-Djava.class.path=lib/somejar1.jar:"
    "bin:"
    "lib/somejar2.jar:"
    "lib/somejar3.jar";
```

When I run this code, the `assert()` code fails, but when I run this (at the same location):

```
java -cp lib/somejar1.jar:bin:lib/somejar2.jar:lib/somejar3.jar my.package.MyClass
```

...everything works fine.

The class I am loading is very simple:

```java
package my.package;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

};
```

I also tried without the `main` method but the result was the same. I can load classes from the JARs without issues, but I cannot load this one class from the `bin` directory...

I have checked many questions, but most of these were about incorrect classpath or incorrect naming convention... I double checked everything and I did not find any issue.

Some other answers mentioned problem with threads, but since I am creating the JVM from a C++ environment, I don't if this apply? And even if it does, this call to `FindClass` should not be problematic?

I would really appreciate a solution to this, or at least a way to debug in more depth what is happening...

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I found the root of the problem, and I am writting this answer because I did not find a canonical one for `FindClass`-related problem.*

The issue was a difference between the `java` version of the `javac` executable used to compile the `.java` file (Java 1.7, standard Java installation on the  machine) and the version of the JNI code (OpenJDK 1.5, custom installation).

Once I compiled the java files with the correct `javac` executable, the code worked without issue.